# Google Tag Manager Drop Down Tracking

Tags: drop-down-menu, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, tracking

I tried to track some drop down fields on my homepage. I tried to track them with Simo Ahava's Tutorial (https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/track-selection-drop-list/) but unfortunately its not working.

Right now every selected drop down field is written in a new datalayer. What I want is to send this informations to google analytics in one datalyer but after clicking 'send' at my homepage formular. What I need is a formular tracking that is reporting the selected dropdowns to Google Analytics.

**EDIT -** 
There are three values I want to track with the tag manager and sent them to Google Analystics.

1. Value: Textfield with the name of the company (the id is: `powermail_field_company`)
2. Value: Dropdown field with the number of employees (the id is: `powermail_field_employee`)
3. Value: Dropdown field with the company branch (the id is: `powermail_field_branch`)

My Idea was to set up a GA - Event Trigger. I tried to collect this information via a Custom JavaScript like this:

```
function() {
  var inputField = document.getElementById("powermail_field_company");
  return inputField.value || "";

  var selectMenu = document.querySelector('#powermail_field_employee');
  return inputField.value || "";

   var selectMenu = document.querySelector('#powermail_field_branch');
  return inputField.value || "";
}
```

Is my custom CSS right ? Is it possible to collect these 3 Values in just one Tag?

Comment: need more details on what is happening and how it is implemented and the current structure of html you are implementing on. Please edit the question to add the details

Comment: Please edit the question to add the details

Comment: in which report would you like to see the 3 parameters that you are sending?

Comment: The three Parameters should be shown as Events in my Google Analytics Account

Comment: Different events or all 3 in one event?

Comment: all 3 in one event would be the best